# Unit test of RxJava combineLatest hangs when single thread scheduler is used

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to write unit test for a function that uses combineLatest.Here is the simplified version of my test:

```
@Test
public void testCombined() {
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxJavaSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getIOScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }

        @Override
        public Scheduler getNewThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }

        @Override
        public Scheduler getComputationScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });

    Observable<String> observable1 = Observable.just("hello");
    Observable<String> observable2 = Observable.just("world");

    Observable<String> combined = Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
    String result = combined.toBlocking().first();
    System.out.println( result);
}
```

This testcase hangs when executed. If I remove the scheduler hook, it runs fine. Any idea why this is case and how can I work around the problem?

Comment: I don't recommend writing test like this as you cannot reset these schedulers.

Comment: I put the scheduler initialization code in a @BeforeSuite method. I embedded the code here to make it self contained.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known anomaly](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3924) in RxJava: some internal housekeeping prevents running anything if the computation scheduler is replaced with the immediate scheduler.

The fix will be part of 1.1.6 - I'd expect it to be released within 2 weeks.

Comment: Related Q: Is there a way to set which scheduler the combineLatest uses inline? I think he can do the rest with DI. Personal motive: I would very much like to combine the result of getting android map view and a observable data set when map becomes available and obs emitting, but with combineLatest seemingly unable to run on the mainThread, I resort to a wrapper object...

Comment: This is not related to combineLatest but to a family of operators (flatMap, zip) which internally use some pooled resources whose cleanup task, by default, runs on a background thread. By replacing the computation scheduler, you basically get a repeated sleep that happens in the constructor of the related operator. The plugin system is quite old and awkwardly designed so I wouldn't use it but inject the TestScheduler whenever needed.